# Hide iOS keyboard tab bar in a web app

Tags: css, ios, web-applications, keyboard

I am a making a small iOS web app with a chat feature. The problem is that I don't seem to able to get rid of the tab bar that appears when I focus on my text field. That tab bar is absolutely redundant there, since is it taking up vital screen space and is not functional as I only have one input field.

Is there a way to make it go away somehow?

[image]

Comment: I know that if you use these two META tags (<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />) you will be able to reduce the size of the browser screen.. sorry I also tried searching.. unless there is a way you can make this area a fullscreen window but I guess this is a web app with HTML5 and not cocoa so you don't have full control over the interface .. even then I am sure you can use javascript to make a text div and then say onclick expand a hidden div which is the javascript of this keyboard.. same design etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been searching around and it doesn't seem possible. I guess in your scenario here, it makes sense for it to be hidden, but then you'd loose the 'done' functionality as you don't seem to have a 'Go' option, which would be the best scenario for users?

To help you in your search, that bar is called the "Form assistant". I really couldn't find much except to say it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same thought with a search keyboard and only one field. Since the return key is the "search key" I wouldn't even need the "done" button. But it seems that it is not (yet) possible to remove that line. it is possible to force the search or number keyboard though, so maybe it will be added by apple in the future.